# How to make a vertical range plot filled with color using CorePlot in iOS?

Tags: ios, core-plot

I need to show a graph in my iOS app something like

[image]

We have been using CorePlot for all the graphs and now I need to add a new kind as shown above. I found I could draw a graph like the above with CPTRangePlot. My problem is I can only draw a horizontal graph as shown below.

[image]

Is there any way to make it vertical? For a single curve we can easily do that by switching the value on X-axis and Y-axis. But for this kind of "range plot", I could not find a way to make it work for drawing the upper-bound and lower-bound lines and filling range with color can only be achieved on a normal horizontal graph. And yes, I can easily rotate the container view by 90 degrees, as I did in my testbed app. But I just cannot do this in our current app because this new added "range plot" graph is not the only one on the view. We have many other curves sharing the same plot space. So is there any hidden property or method to achieve the job? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I just added a `fillDirection` property to the range plot to enable this feature. You'll need to use the latest code from the `release-2.3` branch.

Comment: Thank you so much! That saves me tons of time.

Comment: I am not able to download release-2.3 with CocoaPods. I was using    pod 'CorePlot', :git => 'https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot.git', :branch => 'release-2.3'    and "pod install" always installs CorePlot 2.2.

Comment: That should get the latest on the `release-2.3` branch. The version number in the podspec on that branch still reads 2.2. Check to see if the new `fillDirection` property is available on `CPTRangePlot`. If so, you have the latest version.